# How to scrape email and phone numbers from a list of websites?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a file with name and links of the websites.

How do I write a program that helps me scrape phone number and email from all the websites?

[image]

Comment: Hi, your question is too broad - see here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a guide. Especially your prior code attempts and sample data is required to help.

Comment: You didn't attach a reference of what you need to collect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be sort of tricky as each website is likely different. But you can try to use some common identifiers to get phone or email by doing a `soup.select("a[href*=mailto]")` or `soup.select("a[href*=callto]")`. You could also use regular expression to pull out string within the html text that match what you would assume to be a phone number and/or email address. This will of course pull out ALL emails or phones it finds, so I have to make a few assumptions.

It's not perfect, but should hopefully get you going:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import bs4
import re


src_df = pd.read_csv('C:/src_file.csv')


def get_phone(soup):
    try:
        phone = soup.select("a[href*=callto]")[0].text
        return phone
    except:
        pass

    try:
        phone = re.findall(r'\(?\b[2-9][0-9]{2}\)?[-][2-9][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{4}\b', response.text)[0]
        return phone
    except:
        pass

    try:
       phone = re.findall(r'\(?\b[2-9][0-9]{2}\)?[-. ]?[2-9][0-9]{2}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}\b', response.text)[-1]
       return phone
    except:
        print ('Phone number not found')
        phone = ''
        return phone



def get_email(soup):
    try:
        email = re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)', response.text)[-1]
        return email
    except:
        pass

    try:
        email = soup.select("a[href*=mailto]")[-1].text
    except:
        print ('Email not found')
        email = ''
        return email


for i, row in src_df.iterrows():
    url = 'http://www.' + row['website']
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    except:
        print ('Unsucessful: ' + str(response))
        continue

    phone = get_phone(soup)
    email = get_email(soup)

    src_df.loc[i,'Phone'] = phone
    src_df.loc[i,'Email'] = email
    print ('website:%s\nphone: %s\nemail: %s\n' %(url, phone, email))

src_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (src_df)
                       Organization              ...                                        Email
0      California Community College              ...                   tcalhoon@ccctechcenter.org
1        Colorado Community College              ...                 cccs.communications@cccs.edu
2  Raritan Valley Community College              ...                Cheryl.Wallace@RaritanVal.edu

[3 rows x 5 columns]
```